# can bound negative space be used in SVG?

Tags: svg

If I have a map of three countries, and their borders form the outline of a sea, is their a way with SVG to give that bound area attributes and style?

Another example might be three triangles which form a third triangle in the center (like the triforce). If someone wanted to make that middle empty area glow (or whatever)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would have to compute the bound shape and create that as a separate object.

However, let's say that you wanted to draw a map of the world. You could create a rectangle that was completely blue (for the water), and then draw all the countries on top of that. Then you wouldn't have to compute separate objects for all the various bodies of water.

Comment: The only problem with that solution is if I wanted to style each body of water differently.  Or add a label to the body of water that was at the center of the bound space.  As far as creating the bound areas (or compute them, as you aptly put it), the issue is with trying to write something by hand.  It's not very difficult to draw basic shapes with a text editor, but figuring out the reverse coordinates because really painful really fast.  Definitely should be added to a working draft.

Comment: @Anthony: See also `veExclude`: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/vectoreffects.html It may do what you want, but I don't know if any SVG engine implements it.

Answer (score 0):

With the triangles I'd say just draw the middle triangle 'again', or actually before your draw the 3 triangles. For the sea any simple shape fully covered by the 3 countries will do.